# Datasnap XE2 : how to send abstract classes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I'm currently trying to receive a complex object from my datasnap server.

This object contains property of type : TList< AnAbstractClass >
I populate this TList with classes inheriting from AnAbstractClass.

But client side , EConversionError occurs. if I replace TList< AnAbstractClass > by TList< AConcreteClass > everything is fine, so the problem is in inheritance.

Is there a mean to do that ?

rgds

Comment: Seems like you should just declare the base class as TList of your descendant class. :-) Why bother with the abstract base class if you want Datasnap to be able to send it? Imagine You were datasnap. How would you guess what type to instantiate to populate the list on the other side of the connection?

Comment: The point is that I have several classes descendant of the base class ; And client side should know which class to instanciate in the same manner than any other type of class.

Comment: And what manner is that? Please explain it. Because you are expecting Magic.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I need probably to create my own JSON serialization methode to perform that, but I'll  not have the time to do that .....